# Set background as transparent/white when the image moves by CSS transition

Tags: html, css

My code for a Video Gallery is below and almost everything is working fine, but you can see in the image there is a small "gap" of black color before the image is hovered, is there anyway to remove it or replace the color?

[image]

I want to "keep" the transition and the background color.

Here is the code pen: https://codepen.io/wavyblues/pen/poyBbeL

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>My Example</title>

<style>
  .video-gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  /* min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 360px; */
  width: 48%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: .45;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;

  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption,
.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption > a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}


.video-gallery .gallery-item h2,
.video-gallery .gallery-item p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68%;

  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover img {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption {
  text-align: left;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;

  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover h2::after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .video-gallery .gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

</style>
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="section-header">Video Gallery</h1>
  <div class="section-header-underline"></div>
  <div class="video-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/inception_movie_poster_banner_04.jpg">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Inception</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item ">
      <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/dark-knight-rises-movie-poster-banner-catwoman.jpg" alt="Mt. Rainier">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Dark Knight</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rD8Unfk.jpg" alt="Olympic National Park">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Warcraft</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fscottmendelson%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F07%2FJustice-League-SDCC-Banner.jpg" alt="Mount St. Helens">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Justice League</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are having difficulty doing this is because the black background is part of the container but you are applying the transition to the image itself - which is working independently of the black background.

You can get around this by simply putting the image into its own container with a black background, and then applying the transition to it.

**Working Example:**

```css
.video-gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  /* min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 360px; */
  width: 48%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  background: #000;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: .45;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption,
.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption>a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2,
.video-gallery .gallery-item p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68%;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0);
}


.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover .gallery-item-img {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover img {
  opacity: .3;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption {
  text-align: left;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover h2::after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .video-gallery .gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h1 class="section-header">Video Gallery</h1>
  <div class="section-header-underline"></div>
  <div class="video-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-item-img">
        <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/inception_movie_poster_banner_04.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Inception</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item ">
      <div class="gallery-item-img">
        <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/dark-knight-rises-movie-poster-banner-catwoman.jpg" alt="Mt. Rainier">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Dark Knight</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-item-img">
        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rD8Unfk.jpg" alt="Olympic National Park">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Warcraft</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item">
      <div class="gallery-item-img">
        <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fscottmendelson%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F07%2FJustice-League-SDCC-Banner.jpg" alt="Mount St. Helens">
      </div>
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Justice League</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

**The main changes you need to make are:**

1. Add the images to a container div with a class `gallery-item-img` for example, e.g.:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
  <div class="gallery-item-img">
    <img src="https://www.example.com/image.jpg">
  </div>
  REST OF THE ITEM HERE....
</div>
```

2. Move the black background and transition to this class:

```
.video-gallery .gallery-item-img {
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover .gallery-item-img {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

3. Set the height, width & opacity of the image itself:

```
.video-gallery .gallery-item img {
  display: block;
  opacity: .45;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover img {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ,look like i misplaced the the div and caused the error .

Comment: @greenboxgoolu There was nothing actually wrong with the divs you had... you just had to add an extra div as a container for both the image and black background so you could move them as a single unit :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `-20px` offset in your `transform`. `transform: translate3d(-20px, 0, 0);` to `transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);`

```css
  .video-gallery {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10px 1%;
  /* min-width: 500px;
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 360px; */
  width: 48%;
  background: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item img {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  opacity: .45;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;

  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption {
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption,
.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption > a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2 {
  font-weight: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0.5em 0;
}


.video-gallery .gallery-item h2,
.video-gallery .gallery-item p {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item p {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 68%;

  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  transform: translate3d(10%, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover img {
  opacity: .3;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);

}

.video-gallery .gallery-item .gallery-item-caption {
  text-align: left;
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item h2::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 15%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;

  transition: transform 0.3s;
  transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover h2::after {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.video-gallery .gallery-item:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 50em) {
  .video-gallery .gallery-item {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    margin: 10px auto;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>My Example</title>

<div class="content">
  <h1 class="section-header">Video Gallery</h1>
  <div class="section-header-underline"></div>
  <div class="video-gallery">
    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/inception_movie_poster_banner_04.jpg">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Inception</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item ">
      <img src="https://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/dark-knight-rises-movie-poster-banner-catwoman.jpg" alt="Mt. Rainier">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Dark Knight</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://i.imgur.com/rD8Unfk.jpg" alt="Olympic National Park">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Warcraft</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gallery-item">
      <img src="https://thumbor.forbes.com/thumbor/960x0/https%3A%2F%2Fblogs-images.forbes.com%2Fscottmendelson%2Ffiles%2F2017%2F07%2FJustice-League-SDCC-Banner.jpg" alt="Mount St. Helens">
      <div class="gallery-item-caption">
        <div>
          <h2>Justice League</h2>
          <p></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply , but by removing the transform3d , it will make the "transition" effect static .

Comment: @greenboxgoolu My answer didn't say to remove transform3d